# Youtube Javascript API: start parameter not working on replay

Tags: iframe, youtube, embed, replay

I'm working with the Youtube Javascript API (iframe version) and I'm using  `start` and `end` parameters in order to play a portion only of a video. While everything works fine, once the `end` is reach, the player stop (normal behavior). However, when clicking again on **play**, the player does not seems to considering the `start` option. It always restart playing from the beginning of the video. It ends however at the defined `end` value, always.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5lGoQhFb4NM?autoplay=1&autohide=1&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&controls=0&vq=hd720&rel=0&start=60&end=100" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></iframe>
```

Do you guys have any idea on why it is happening?

Comment: What did you end up doing ?

Comment: @httpete Well, since I was originaly using Angular, I ended up using https://github.com/brandly/angular-youtube-embed which which allowed me to reload the iframe using the event `youtube.player.ended`. If you are interested, I will post my solution here as an answer, just let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I was able to have the replay button start over at the original `start` time, as well as prevent users from scrolling outside the start/end bounds of the `playerVars`:

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

  var isClip = playerOptions.playerVars.start && playerOptions.playerVars.end;
  var start = isClip ? playerOptions.playerVars.start : null;
  var end = isClip ? playerOptions.playerVars.end : null;

  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    if (isClip) {
      var currentTime = event.target.getCurrentTime();
      if (currentTime < start || currentTime > end) {
        event.target.seekTo(playerOptions.playerVars.start);
      }
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the above solution without succes (error console : "playerOptions is not defined")

But thx to this topic [YouTube API - Loop video between set start and end times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271570/youtube-api-loop-video-between-set-start-and-end-times) I've been able to successfully get the start/end parameters on replay :

```
 <script>
// 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
   
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        var playButton = document.getElementById("play");
        playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
            player.loadVideoById({
                  videoId: videoId,
                  startSeconds: startSeconds,
                  endSeconds: endSeconds
            });
        });
        document.getElementById("play").style.cssText = "visibility:visible";
    }  
  }
 </script>
```

Explanations : in my case, I'm using a button id="play" to start the video. When the video is ENDED, the button #play is set to visibility:visible and the click event uses the player.loadVideoById corresponding parameters.
If you don't use the click event, the video will auto loop with the desired start/end values.

From Youtube API reference =  https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=fr#Getting_Started