# YouTube API - Loop video between set start and end times

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I've managed to start the video and end the video at the times I need, but is there any way to loop this?  The loop option doesn't seem to be doing much.

**Fiddle:**  https://jsfiddle.net/u7nkz292/

**Code:**

```
<div id="ytplayer"></div>



<script>
  // Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
  // YouTube player after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '360',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE', 
          playerVars: {
      autoplay: 1,        // Auto-play the video on load
      controls: 0,        // Show pause/play buttons in player
      showinfo: 0,        // Hide the video title
      modestbranding: 1,  // Hide the Youtube Logo
      fs: 1,              // Hide the full screen button
      cc_load_policy: 0, // Hide closed captions
      iv_load_policy: 3,  // Hide the Video Annotations
      start: 36,
      end: 45,
      loop: 1,            // Run the video in a loop
      autohide: 0         // Hide video controls when playing
    },
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410789/youtube-player-api-with-loop)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can implement `onStateChange` callback & load the video with the same `startSeconds` & `endSeconds` parameter with [`loadVideoById`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#loadVideoById) :

```
// Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var videoId = 'M7lc1UVf-VE';
var startSeconds = 36;
var endSeconds = 45;

// Replace the 'ytplayer' element with an <iframe> and
// YouTube player after the API code downloads.
var player;

var playerConfig = {
  height: '360',
  width: '640',
  videoId: videoId,
  playerVars: {
    autoplay: 1, // Auto-play the video on load
    controls: 0, // Show pause/play buttons in player
    showinfo: 0, // Hide the video title
    modestbranding: 1, // Hide the Youtube Logo
    fs: 1, // Hide the full screen button
    cc_load_policy: 0, // Hide closed captions
    iv_load_policy: 3, // Hide the Video Annotations
    start: startSeconds,
    end: endSeconds,
    autohide: 0, // Hide video controls when playing
  },
  events: {
    'onStateChange': onStateChange
  }
};

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', playerConfig);
}

function onStateChange(state) {
  if (state.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
    player.loadVideoById({
      videoId: videoId,
      startSeconds: startSeconds,
      endSeconds: endSeconds
    });
  }
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bmartel/u7nkz292/5/) is a Fiddle

Comment: That's perfect.  Thank you!

Comment: if i seat       autoplay: 0 it is not disabling auto play

Answer (score 11):

Iterating on Bertrand Martel's great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42281973/1188090) above:

If you're looping on the same video, I've found you can minimize the delay in between loops by calling `player.seekTo(startSeconds)`instead of `player.loadVideoById(...)`. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/xzdhmejg/) is a fiddle comparing the performance of both approaches.