"endAt" will not work for me with YTPlayer and I'm not sure why
I'm using a YouTube video as a background on my website, and playing it with YTPlayer. However, when I try to use "endAt," will not not work. The video will instead play to the end. startAt works as expected. Here's the code:
<div class="thevideo">
          <div
            class="video-player"
            data-property="{videoURL:'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VwWY-Zh-KLM', containment:'.home-section', startAt:30, endAt:60, mute:true, autoPlay:true, loop:true, opacity:1, showControls:false, showYTLogo:false}"
          ></div>
        </div>


The issue with endAt not functioning in YTPlayer may be related to how certain versions handle looping. In some cases, YTPlayer does not fully support the endAt setting, especially when looping is enabled.
Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42281973/12421879
